# Material UI beta, table with global search

Tags: reactjs, search, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I am using last Material-UI react component library, and try to add global search through the whole table. I try to use regex to global and case sensitive behavior. But I'll catch the error:

> match is not a function

Who knows a better solution how to add searching with Material-UI table.

[Online VS Code IDE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-csuz3d)

The part of search field function

```
 const columnData = [
  { id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Dessert (100g serving)' },
  { id: 'calories', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Calories' },
  { id: 'fat', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Fat (g)' },
  { id: 'carbs', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Carbs (g)' },
  { id: 'protein', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Protein (g)' },
];

 handleSearch = value => {
    const {searchValue, data} = this.state
    this.setState({searchValue: event.target.value})
    let filteredDatas = []
    filteredDatas = data.filter(e => {
        let mathesItems = Object.values(e)
        return mathesItems.some(e => {
            const regex = new RegExp(searchValue, 'gi')
            if (typeof e == 'string')
                return e.match(regex)
            else
              return false
        })
    })
    console.log(filteredDatas)
    this.setState({data: filteredDatas})
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` is prototype of `string` not  `number`. **[DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**

In you code when the filter is executed `e` param is `string` as well as `number`.
So the `number` does not have `match` function. I have modified by identifying the type and then add the logic accordingly. Like

```
return arr.filter (e => {
    const regex = new RegExp(value, 'gi')
    if(typeof e == "string")
        return e.match(regex)
    else
        return false
   })
```

**Update :**

I am not able to save live code, update `index.js` file with below code. and its working

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles, createStyleSheet } from 'material-ui/styles';
import keycode from 'keycode';
import Table, {
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableSortLabel,
} from 'material-ui/Table';
import Toolbar from 'material-ui/Toolbar';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import DeleteIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Delete';
import FilterListIcon from 'material-ui-icons/FilterList';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

let counter = 0;
function createData(name, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  counter += 1;
  return { id: counter, name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const columnData = [
  { id: 'name', numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: 'Dessert (100g serving)' },
  { id: 'calories', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Calories' },
  { id: 'fat', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Fat (g)' },
  { id: 'carbs', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Carbs (g)' },
  { id: 'protein', numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: 'Protein (g)' },
];

class EnhancedTableHead extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    order: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  createSortHandler = property => event => {
    this.props.onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  render() {
    const { onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, } = this.props;

    return (
      <TableHead>
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell checkbox>
            <Checkbox
              indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < 5}
              checked={numSelected === 5}
              onChange={onSelectAllClick}
            />
          </TableCell>
          {columnData.map(column => {
            return (
              <TableCell
                key={column.id}
                numeric={column.numeric}
                disablePadding={column.disablePadding}
              >
                <TableSortLabel
                  active={orderBy === column.id}
                  direction={order}
                  onClick={this.createSortHandler(column.id)}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableSortLabel>
              </TableCell>
            );
          }, this)}
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    );
  }
}

const toolbarStyleSheet = createStyleSheet(theme => ({
  root: {
    paddingRight: 2,
  },
  highlight:
    theme.palette.type === 'light'
      ? {
          color: theme.palette.accent.A700,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.accent.A100,
        }
      : {
          color: theme.palette.accent.A100,
          backgroundColor: theme.palette.accent.A700,
        },
  actions: {
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    marginLeft: 'auto'
  },
  title: {
    flex: '0 0 auto',
  },
}));

let EnhancedTableToolbar = props => {
  const { numSelected, classes, value, handleSearch} = props;

  return (
    <Toolbar
      className={classNames(classes.root, {
        [classes.highlight]: numSelected > 0,
      })}
    >
      <div className={classes.title}>
        {numSelected > 0
          ? <Typography type="subheading">
              {numSelected} selected
            </Typography>
          : <Typography type="title">Nutrition</Typography>}
      </div>
      <div className={classes.actions}>
        {numSelected > 0
          ? <IconButton aria-label="Delete">
              <DeleteIcon />
            </IconButton>
          : <div>
              <TextField  placeholder="Search" onChange={handleSearch} value={value}/>
              <IconButton aria-label="Filter list">
                <FilterListIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </div>
            }
      </div>
    </Toolbar>
  );
};

EnhancedTableToolbar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};

EnhancedTableToolbar = withStyles(toolbarStyleSheet)(EnhancedTableToolbar);

const styleSheet = createStyleSheet(theme => ({
  paper: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    overflowX: 'auto',
  },
}));

class EnhancedTable extends Component {
  state = {
    order: 'asc',
    orderBy: 'calories',
    selected: [],
    searchValue: '',
    data: [
      createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
      createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
      createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
      createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
      createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
    ],
    filterData: [
      createData('Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
      createData('Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
      createData('Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
      createData('Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
      createData('Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9),
    ],
  };

  handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
    const orderBy = property;
    let order = 'desc';

    if (this.state.orderBy === property && this.state.order === 'desc') {
      order = 'asc';
    }

    const filterData = this.state.filterData.sort(
      (a, b) => (order === 'desc' ? b[orderBy] > a[orderBy] : a[orderBy] > b[orderBy]),
    );

    this.setState({ filterData, order, orderBy });
  };

  handleSelectAllClick = (event, checked) => {
    if (checked) {
      this.setState({ selected: this.state.filterData.map(n => n.id) });
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ selected: [] });
  };

  handleKeyDown = (event, id) => {
    if (keycode(event) === 'space') {
      this.handleClick(event, id);
    }
  };

  handleClick = (event, id) => {
    const { selected } = this.state;
    const selectedIndex = selected.indexOf(id);
    let newSelected = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selected.length - 1) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(selected.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelected = newSelected.concat(
        selected.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selected.slice(selectedIndex + 1),
      );
    }

    this.setState({ selected: newSelected });
  };

  isSelected = id => this.state.selected.indexOf(id) !== -1;


   handleSearch = event => {
        const {data} = this.state
        let filteredDatas = []
        filteredDatas = data.filter(e => {
            let mathesItems = Object.values(e)
            let retVal = true;
            mathesItems.forEach(e => {
                const regex = new RegExp(event.target.value, 'gi')
                if (typeof e == 'string')
                    retVal = e.match(regex)
            })
            return retVal;
        })
        this.setState({filterData: filteredDatas, searchValue: event.target.value})
    }


  render() {
    const classes = this.props.classes;
    const { filterData, order, orderBy, selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} handleSearch={this.handleSearch} 
            value={this.searchValue} />
        <Table>
          <EnhancedTableHead
            numSelected={selected.length}
            order={order}
            orderBy={orderBy}
            onSelectAllClick={this.handleSelectAllClick}
            onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}

          />
          <TableBody>
            {filterData.map(n => {
              const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
              return (
                <TableRow
                  hover
                  onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
                  onKeyDown={event => this.handleKeyDown(event, n.id)}
                  role="checkbox"
                  aria-checked={isSelected}
                  tabIndex="-1"
                  key={n.id}
                  selected={isSelected}
                >
                  <TableCell checkbox>
                    <Checkbox checked={isSelected} />
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell disablePadding>
                    {n.name}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell numeric>
                    {n.calories}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell numeric>
                    {n.fat}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell numeric>
                    {n.carbs}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell numeric>
                    {n.protein}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

EnhancedTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

EnhancedTable = withStyles(styleSheet)(EnhancedTable);

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <EnhancedTable />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Can you review pls, in live example, it still not working
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-csuz3d

Comment: You have to create 2 dataset, one for original data and one for filtered data, and you have to modify only filter data not original data. Original data is base source from there you can filter new dataset. Any doubts...